# Persistent (always shown) tooltip hovers in apexchart js

Tags: javascript, css, charts, styling, apexcharts

I've got a rangebar chart, created with apexcharts.js library integrated into Vue JS 2.0

It's almost done, but I can't find the way to make tooltips hovers permanent right on render, not only on mouseover, which is default behaviour.

Is there a boolean property for that, or any other way to make them persistent near the bars?

[I want tooltips to be always displayed on render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thh4o.png)

I've found an issue on github with advice to add `opacity: 1 !important` to the tooltips, but that didn't helped. I've tried adding inline and in scoped styles. Maybe that fix doesn't work at all. Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Tooltip code:

```
tooltip: {
          enabled: true,
          custom: function ({ seriesIndex, dataPointIndex, w }) {
            let data = w.globals.initialSeries[seriesIndex].data[dataPointIndex]

            let arrOfDates = data.y.map(secs => new Date(secs).toString())

            arrOfDates = arrOfDates.map((element) => {
              let d = new Date(element)
              return `${d.getDate()}.${d.getMonth()+1}.${d.getFullYear()}`
            })

            console.log('arrOfDates: ', arrOfDates)

            return '<div style="background-color: #ECEBED; opacity: 1 !important; display: flex; padding: 5px 16px;">' +
              '<div style="margin-right: 5px";><b>Б: ' +  data.budget + ' р.; ' + '</b>'+ '</div>' +
              '<div style="margin-right: 5px";><b>Д: </b> ' + '<span style="color: green">' + data.finance_profit + ' р.;' + '</span>' + '</div>' +
              '<div style="margin-right: 5px";><b>Р: </b> ' + '<span style="color: red">' + data.finance_expense + ' р.;' + '</span>' + '</div>' +
              '<div style="margin-right: 5px";><b>ДЗ: </b> ' + (data.budget - data.finance_profit) + ' р.; ' + '</div>' +
              '<div style="margin-right: 5px";><b>M: </b> ' + (Math.round((data.finance_profit * 100) / data.budget)) + '%' + '</div>' +
              '</div>'

              // let tooltip = chartContext.el.querySelector('.apexcharts-tooltip');

          },
        },
```

Comment: So were you able to do this? I'm trying to do this now but can't find a solution